# Converting JSON String to Data Class instance in Spring project

Tags: json, spring, jackson, kotlin

In a controller function i get a JSON via `@RequestBody` as `data class`. I want to store the `data class` as string and later turn it back into `data class`.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean store it as a string? As a raw json string?

Comment: Yes, i use .toString() for that

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this but you can get the request body coming through your Controller as raw json by changing the accept header from application/json to plain/text and changing the input parameter from your data class to a String.

You can then turn this into the data class object manually later on by calling the Jackson ObjectMapper class directly.

```
 val mapper = ObjectMapper()
 val myDataObject : MyDataObject = mapper.readvalue(rawJsonString, MyDataObject::class.java)
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try this. I want to do this because i need to log certain requests and their contents in my database.